# FilmRoll jQuery carousel - not working first time loading

Tags: jquery, css, html, carousel

I am using FilmRoll jQuery carousel. [plugin link](https://github.com/straydogstudio/film_roll) [plugin demo](http://straydogstudio.github.io/film_roll/)

Its working fine on desktop browser

**Problem** : not working on iphone first time loads if resize the window( means portrait to landscape )  It will work same as desktop

**Script**

```
    $(function() {
      fr = new FilmRoll({
        container: '#film_roll',
        height:50,
        animation: 1000,
        interval: 10000,
        prev: '#film_roll_prev',
        next: '#film_roll_next'
      });
    });
```

Comment: Do you have a page I can look at?

Comment: The last time this happened it was a problem with vimeo loading in iOS. iOS was not handling the failed load well, and the FilmRoll onload event was not firing: https://github.com/straydogstudio/film_roll/issues/24

Comment: Problem solved with this solution //             setTimeout(function () {
             film_roll.resize();
            }, 100);//

Comment: @noel Please I have another question - How can i disable "next", "prev" button if slide item is single ?

Comment: You know, the library should detect that. In the meantime, you'll have to pass in an id to `next` and `prev` to prevent it from creating them. I would also make them hidden. This is off the top of my head, so I'll look into it more completely when I can and let you know better (or update the library so you can pass false to next and prev.)

Comment: And glad you got that solved. I've solved things in a similar way with setTimeout.

Comment: thanks for your support , Can i remove slider rotation (loop) ?  my client no need rotation :( @noel

Comment: If you aren't needing any rotation and you just have a few images, then it might be easier just to create the markup and drop the plugin! But, that said, turn off scroll (scroll: false), have next and previous refer to hidden elements (yes I will fix that when I can), and pass pager: false to get rid of the buttons across the bottom. What exactly does your client need?

Comment: @noel  Clients need , When the last item appear then slider scrolling effect should stop or next and prev button disabled ,  Please help me may be i can manage your file :) See the demo url http://toobler.com/staging/design/feeba/html/sprint7/feedback-3.html

Comment: When it reaches the end it should stop scrolling? Or should they be able to go back the other way?

Comment: Yes when the reaches end it should stop scroll :)

Comment: I'll post an answer for you, since I can't format it well here.

Comment: Incidentally, I just uploaded a new version that accepts `prev: false` and `next: false`, allowing no next/prev buttons.

Answer (score 0):

An answer for your comment question:

```
var film_roll = new FilmRoll({container: '#container_id',...});
$('#container_id').on('film_roll:moved', function(event) {
  if ( film_roll.index == film_roll.children.length - 1 ) {
    film_roll.clearScroll();
  }
});
```

The 'film_roll:moved' event is called at the end of each animation. Then we check if the current index is on the last child (the length - 1), and clear the scroll animation if so. That will stop on the last item.

Incidentally, if you want to restart the scroll animation, use `film_roll.configureScroll()`.

Comment: Understood your code and idea but nothing happened here , I have created a fiddle please check it out http://jsfiddle.net/Lcfaory9/

Comment: @ShibinRagh When I go to that jsfiddle it stops on the last item (test3). Was that what you were wanting?

Comment: "test3" Yes it should end as last item , Thanks @noel

Comment: @ShibinRagh I'm not sure what is missing. The jsfiddle stops on the last item for me, and from what I understand that is what you want. What do you need that it is not doing? What browser are you using?